# how to store a field in the database after querying

Tags: django, django-queryset

views.py:

```
     q3=KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading__month=a).filter(datetime_reading__year=selected_year).values("signed")
     for item in q3:
       item["signed"]="signed" 
       print item["signed"]
      q3.save()
```

How do I save a field into the database? I'm trying to save the field called "signed" with a value. If I do `q3.save()` it gives a error as it is a queryset. I'm doing a query from the database and then, based on the result, want to set a value to a field and save it.

```
  prevdate=KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading__lt=date)
```

i am getting all the rows from the database less than the current date. but i want only the latest record. if im entering 2012-06-03. wen i query i want the date less than this date i.e the date just previous to this. can sumbody help?

Comment: Make your question little clear for us to understand. Filter query will fetch already saved records and what is the need to save them again?

Comment: That's not the correct codes for saving. Your combining filtering query and saving

Comment: im queryin for all the rows from the DB of a particular month and year. and for each of the row i want to store a value called "yes" for the attribute "signed". i want to store that in the DB(database)

Comment: Hello @prithu, Instead of using item['signed'] (as you would perhaps do in Javascript), you have to use _item.signed_. Use the field as a property of the model instance. Then, since you're looping the q3 object, it's not a single model instance to be saved, but a queryset (like a list). It doesn't have a save method. What you want to do is save each item in each iteration. Good luck.

Comment: @pirthu ok I post answer. Try it and tell me if you got an error

Comment: @prithu So you are try to filter some records and update the value of `signed` field for those records alone. Am I correct?

Comment: @catherine itt gives a error. since q3 doesn have a  save() method. its a queryset. a list of dictionary

Comment: @prithu ok wait, I just notice that you have values signed in your query

Comment: @prithu ok answer updated and I hope it works now

Comment: I hope this *question update* has ended and there will be no more updates that will **add new questions** to the recent question.

Answer (score 0):

```
q3 = KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading__month=a,
    datetime_reading__year=selected_year)       
for item in q3:
   item.signed = True
   item.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [update query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

If `signed` is a [booleanfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield):

```
q3 = KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading__month = a).filter(datetime_reading__year = selected_year).update(signed = True)
```

If it is a [charfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield):

```
q3 = KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading__month = a).filter(datetime_reading__year = selected_year).update(signed = "True")
```

Update for comments:

If you want to fetch records based `datetime_reading` month, you can do it by providing month as number. For example, `2` for February:

```
q3 = KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading__month = 2).order_by('datetime_reading')
```

And if you to fetch records with `signed = True`, you can do it by:

```
q3 = KEBReading.objects.filter(signed = True)
```

If you want to fetch only records of previous date by giving a date, you can use:

```
prevdate = KEBReading.objects.filter(datetime_reading = (date - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)))
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me. also could u tell me how to display the rows from the databse of a particluar month only. like only january or february...     q2=KEBReading.objects.all().order_by('datetime_reading')

Comment: @prithu I have update my answer. Check it. And if it worked, accept the answer please.

Comment: thanks for the help. can u also tel me how to check if the "signed" attribute ts true in the DB

Comment: @prithu Check the last line in my answer. I have updated that already.

Comment: @prithu Happy to help. :) Accept the answer if your queries are resolved.

Comment: if i want to get the latest row from the database how do i get. basically im doing sum calculations with the previous date. if i give latest('field') it gives me the latest date. but if i am entering data in the middle i want the calculations with the previous date not the latest date.

Comment: Make your question little clear. Edit your question instead of adding them in comments.

Comment: @prithu Make your question little clear. Do you want only one previous record or records with date before the date you are giving?

Comment: i need only the previous record.

Comment: @prithu What do you mean by previous? If you give the date 2-February-2013, you the records with the date 1-February-2013. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you pass the date? As a string or date object or datetime object?

Comment: prevdate=KEBReading.objects.latest("datetime_reading"). if i use latest it gives me the latest date entry in the database. this gives me a problem wen i want to insert data sumwher in between. i will be needin date in the record just previous to the current date

Comment: @prithu I have updated my answer. Check it. If you give 02-Feb-2013 as date it will fetch records of date 01-Feb-2013.

Comment: it may be also like if i give a date 02-feb-2013  if 01-feb-2013 is not there it must give 31-jan-2013. the date can be anythin i just eed to retriev the previous date whicever is there in the DB

Comment: @prithu It will work in the way, you are asking. If I give `01-March-2013` it will fetch records with date `28-Feb-2013` which is the previous date. You are making this answer a lengthier discussion. If you have more doubts, refer [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com) and try something on your own. And If you are stuck somewhere, post them as new question and the community will help you. Don't expect the community to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
q3=KEBReading.objects.filter(...)
```

will return you a list of objects. Any instance of a `Django Model` is an object and all `fields` of the instance are attributes of that object. That means, you must use them using `dot (.)` notation.

like:

```
item.signed = "signed"
```

If your object is a `dictionary` or a class derived from dictionary, then you can use named-index like:

```
item["signed"] = "signed"
```

and in your situation, that usage is invalid (because your object's type is not `dictionary` based)

You can either call [update query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

```
KEBReading.objects.filter(...).update(selected="selected")
```

or set new value in a loop and then save it

```
for item in q3:
   item.signed="signed" 
   q3.save()
```

but in your situation, update query is a better approach since it executes less database calls.